# Multiclient server socket doesn't print the client messages

Tags: c, sockets

I'm trying to implement a client-server application with multiclients using threads. Just to try, I would like to print the messages from each client, but when I send messages from a client, the server does not print anything.

Server (thread code)

```
void comunicationHandler(void *socket)
{
    int sock = *(int*) socket;
    char msg[2000];

    while ((strcmp(msg, "!quit")) != 0) {
        if (recv(sock, msg, 2000, 0) < 0)
            puts("Error recv");
        printf("%s", msg);
    }
    puts("Client Disconnected\n");
}
```

when I send "!quit", the Server goes in a infinite loop printing the messages

Client

```
for(;;) {
    printf("\nInserisci il msg: ");
    scanf("%s", msg);
    if (strcmp(msg, "!quit") == 0)
        break;
    write(sd, msg, 2000);
}
```

Comment: Try printf("%s\n", msg); instead ... stdout won't flush its buffer until it encounters a newline.

Comment: You should look into [proper C formatting](//prohackr112.tk/r/proper-c-formatting). Or learn how to [thoroughly obfuscate your code](//prohackr112.tk/r/proper-c-obfuscation).

Comment: "*when I send "!quit",*" you don't, but `break` out of the `for`-loop.

Comment: I send it with the scanf and write in client.

Comment: Your `write` only comes after the `break`. You will not send the message.

Comment: I think that if msg is not equal to "!quit", the write will be done (break not executed)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are multiple problems with your code:

1. TCP is stream based, there is no guarantee that all the bytes you send will be received in one shot on the other side. You need to modify code to check what is the number of bytes received and is it atleast equal to the size of "!quit" before you go in for the "strcmp" comparison.
2. Better to null terminate the buffer once you receive the buffer equal to the size of "!quit"
3. It is not clear as to why you are sending a 2000 bytes buffer from the client when you intend to send only "!quit". Modify and send only appropriate size as needed
4. Check recv return value against 0 also
5. Break out of the loop in both server and client once the Job is done.

Answer (score 1):

> Server goes in a infinite loop

You want to test `recv()`'s result against `0` and quit in this case. `0` indicates that the client orderly closed the connection.